# using LEAST in SQL query when using PHP PDO Prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i am trying to use this PHP PDO prepared statement to run an SQL Query:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT *, LEAST(:col_list) as num FROM callplandata WHERE number LIKE :number HAVING num != 0 ");
            $stmt->execute(array(':col_list' => implode(',',$column_list), ':number' => '%'.$_POST["prefix"].'%'));
```

but its showing this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'LEAST'' in /home/integra/public_html/included_pages/call_tarrif_search.php:62 Stack trace: #0 /home/integra/public_html/included_pages/call_tarrif_search.php(62): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /home/integra/public_html/index.php(119): include('/home/integra/p...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/integra/public_html/included_pages/call_tarrif_search.php on line 62
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`LEAST` accepts 2 or more values and returns the least one.

You're passing a single value, that is the roots of the error.

PS: and as soon as you haven't explained the original issue - there is nothing to add here. Please don't ask "how to fix it" because we have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: it works using normal MySQL queries, I've just changed it to be a prepared statement

Comment: @user2710234: seems like you don't understand what placeholder is: `LEAST(:col_list)` means that `:col_list` will be substituted with a **SINGLE** string literal. You cannot pass there `a,b,c` and expect it to become `LEAST(a,b,c)`, it will be `LEAST('a,b,c')` instead. The prepared statement placeholders are to be used with **values** not with objects. So the column names should be inserted in the query manually, just with concatenation

Comment: so would it be okay to do LEAST('".implode(',',$column_list)."') - I'm very new to PDO and prepared statements so please be patient if I'm being a bit stupid :)

Comment: @user2710234: if every column in the `$column_list` is whitelisted - it's fine. PS: not sure why you need single quotes there